# Refresh component template - Angular 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a Angular 2 component to load a view from MVC controller. The code works good, i'm getting the template rendered with Razor but i need to refresh the component every time is open. There's a way to force to reload the component every time is open?

Here my component.

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: '/Template/Index'
})
export class MVCTemplateComponent {}
```

Controller method:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   // Do something
   return PartialView();
}
```

I'm using a router to load the components

Comment: Refreshing will give you a little overhead so the navigation should be done inside the component's template.